# Line graph not connecting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
df = structure(list(dteday = c("01/01/2011", "01/01/2012", "01/02/2011", 
                          "01/02/2012", "01/03/2011", "01/03/2012", "01/04/2011", "01/04/2012", 
                          "01/05/2011", "01/05/2012", "01/06/2011", "01/06/2012", "01/07/2011", 
                          "01/07/2012", "01/08/2011", "01/08/2012", "01/09/2011", "01/09/2012", 
                          "01/10/2011", "01/10/2012", "01/11/2011", "01/11/2012", "01/12/2011", 
                          "01/12/2012", "02/01/2011", "02/01/2012", "02/02/2011", "02/02/2012", 
                          "02/03/2011", "02/03/2012", "02/04/2011", "02/04/2012", "02/05/2011", 
                          "02/05/2012", "02/06/2011", "02/06/2012", "02/07/2011", "02/07/2012", 
                          "02/08/2011", "02/08/2012", "02/09/2011", "02/09/2012", "02/10/2011", 
                          "02/10/2012", "02/11/2011", "02/11/2012", "02/12/2011", "02/12/2012", 
                          "03/01/2011", "03/01/2012", "03/02/2011", "03/02/2012", "03/03/2011", 
                          "03/03/2012", "03/04/2011", "03/04/2012", "03/05/2011", "03/05/2012", 
                          "03/06/2011", "03/06/2012", "03/07/2011", "03/07/2012", "03/08/2011", 
                          "03/08/2012", "03/09/2011", "03/09/2012", "03/10/2011", "03/10/2012", 
                          "03/11/2011", "03/11/2012", "03/12/2011", "03/12/2012", "04/01/2011", 
                          "04/01/2012", "04/02/2011", "04/02/2012", "04/03/2011", "04/03/2012", 
                          "04/04/2011", "04/04/2012", "04/05/2011", "04/05/2012", "04/06/2011", 
                          "04/06/2012", "04/07/2011", "04/07/2012", "04/08/2011", "04/08/2012", 
                          "04/09/2011", "04/09/2012", "04/10/2011", "04/10/2012", "04/11/2011", 
                          "04/11/2012", "04/12/2011", "04/12/2012", "05/01/2011", "05/01/2012", 
                          "05/02/2011", "05/02/2012", "05/03/2011", "05/03/2012", "05/04/2011", 
                          "05/04/2012", "05/05/2011", "05/05/2012", "05/06/2011", "05/06/2012", 
                          "05/07/2011", "05/07/2012", "05/08/2011", "05/08/2012", "05/09/2011", 
                          "05/09/2012", "05/10/2011", "05/10/2012", "05/11/2011", "05/11/2012", 
                          "05/12/2011", "05/12/2012", "06/01/2011", "06/01/2012", "06/02/2011", 
                          "06/02/2012", "06/03/2011", "06/03/2012", "06/04/2011", "06/04/2012", 
                          "06/05/2011", "06/05/2012", "06/06/2011", "06/06/2012", "06/07/2011", 
                          "06/07/2012", "06/08/2011", "06/08/2012", "06/09/2011", "06/09/2012", 
                          "06/10/2011", "06/10/2012", "06/11/2011", "06/11/2012", "06/12/2011", 
                          "06/12/2012", "07/01/2011", "07/01/2012", "07/02/2011", "07/02/2012", 
                          "07/03/2011", "07/03/2012", "07/04/2011", "07/04/2012", "07/05/2011", 
                          "07/05/2012", "07/06/2011", "07/06/2012", "07/07/2011", "07/07/2012", 
                          "07/08/2011", "07/08/2012", "07/09/2011", "07/09/2012", "07/10/2011", 
                          "07/10/2012", "07/11/2011", "07/11/2012", "07/12/2011", "07/12/2012", 
                          "08/01/2011", "08/01/2012", "08/02/2011", "08/02/2012", "08/03/2011", 
                          "08/03/2012", "08/04/2011", "08/04/2012", "08/05/2011", "08/05/2012", 
                          "08/06/2011", "08/06/2012", "08/07/2011", "08/07/2012", "08/08/2011", 
                          "08/08/2012", "08/09/2011", "08/09/2012", "08/10/2011", "08/10/2012", 
                          "08/11/2011", "08/11/2012", "08/12/2011", "08/12/2012", "09/01/2011", 
                          "09/01/2012", "09/02/2011", "09/02/2012", "09/03/2011", "09/03/2012", 
                          "09/04/2011", "09/04/2012", "09/05/2011", "09/05/2012", "09/06/2011", 
                          "09/06/2012", "09/07/2011", "09/07/2012", "09/08/2011", "09/08/2012", 
                          "09/09/2011", "09/09/2012", "09/10/2011", "09/10/2012", "09/11/2011", 
                          "09/11/2012", "09/12/2011", "09/12/2012", "10/01/2011", "10/01/2012", 
                          "10/02/2011", "10/02/2012", "10/03/2012", "10/04/2011", "10/04/2012", 
                          "10/05/2011", "10/05/2012", "10/06/2011", "10/06/2012", "10/07/2011", 
                          "10/07/2012", "10/08/2011", "10/08/2012", "10/09/2011", "10/09/2012", 
                          "10/10/2011", "10/10/2012", "10/11/2011", "10/11/2012", "10/12/2011", 
                          "10/12/2012", "11/01/2011", "11/01/2012", "11/02/2011", "11/02/2012", 
                          "11/03/2011", "11/03/2012", "11/04/2011", "11/04/2012", "11/05/2011", 
                          "11/05/2012", "11/06/2011", "11/06/2012", "11/07/2011", "11/07/2012", 
                          "11/08/2011", "11/08/2012", "11/09/2011", "11/09/2012", "11/10/2011", 
                          "11/10/2012", "11/11/2011", "11/11/2012", "11/12/2011", "11/12/2012", 
                          "12/01/2011", "12/01/2012", "12/02/2011", "12/02/2012", "12/03/2011", 
                          "12/03/2012", "12/04/2011", "12/04/2012", "12/05/2011", "12/05/2012", 
                          "12/06/2011", "12/06/2012", "12/07/2011", "12/07/2012", "12/08/2011", 
                          "12/08/2012", "12/09/2011", "12/09/2012", "12/10/2011", "12/10/2012", 
                          "12/11/2011", "12/11/2012", "12/12/2011", "12/12/2012", "13/01/2011", 
                          "13/01/2012", "13/02/2011", "13/02/2012", "13/03/2011", "13/03/2012", 
                          "13/04/2011", "13/04/2012", "13/05/2011", "13/05/2012", "13/06/2011", 
                          "13/06/2012", "13/07/2011", "13/07/2012", "13/08/2011", "13/08/2012", 
                          "13/09/2011", "13/09/2012", "13/10/2011", "13/10/2012", "13/11/2011", 
                          "13/11/2012", "13/12/2011", "13/12/2012", "14/01/2011", "14/01/2012", 
                          "14/02/2011", "14/02/2012", "14/03/2011", "14/03/2012", "14/04/2011", 
                          "14/04/2012", "14/05/2011", "14/05/2012", "14/06/2011", "14/06/2012", 
                          "14/07/2011", "14/07/2012", "14/08/2011", "14/08/2012", "14/09/2011", 
                          "14/09/2012", "14/10/2011", "14/10/2012", "14/11/2011", "14/11/2012", 
                          "14/12/2011", "14/12/2012", "15/01/2011", "15/01/2012", "15/02/2011", 
                          "15/02/2012", "15/03/2011", "15/03/2012", "15/04/2011", "15/04/2012", 
                          "15/05/2011", "15/05/2012", "15/06/2011", "15/06/2012", "15/07/2011", 
                          "15/07/2012", "15/08/2011", "15/08/2012", "15/09/2011", "15/09/2012", 
                          "15/10/2011", "15/10/2012", "15/11/2011", "15/11/2012", "15/12/2011", 
                          "15/12/2012", "16/01/2011", "16/01/2012", "16/02/2011", "16/02/2012", 
                          "16/03/2011", "16/03/2012", "16/04/2011", "16/04/2012", "16/05/2011", 
                          "16/05/2012", "16/06/2011", "16/06/2012", "16/07/2011", "16/07/2012", 
                          "16/08/2011", "16/08/2012", "16/09/2011", "16/09/2012", "16/10/2011", 
                          "16/10/2012", "16/11/2011", "16/11/2012", "16/12/2011", "16/12/2012", 
                          "17/01/2011", "17/01/2012", "17/02/2011", "17/02/2012", "17/03/2011", 
                          "17/03/2012", "17/04/2011", "17/04/2012", "17/05/2011", "17/05/2012", 
                          "17/06/2011", "17/06/2012", "17/07/2011", "17/07/2012", "17/08/2011", 
                          "17/08/2012", "17/09/2011", "17/09/2012", "17/10/2011", "17/10/2012", 
                          "17/11/2011", "17/11/2012", "17/12/2011", "17/12/2012", "18/01/2011", 
                          "18/01/2012", "18/02/2011", "18/02/2012", "18/03/2011", "18/03/2012", 
                          "18/04/2011", "18/04/2012", "18/05/2011", "18/05/2012", "18/06/2011", 
                          "18/06/2012", "18/07/2011", "18/07/2012", "18/08/2011", "18/08/2012", 
                          "18/09/2011", "18/09/2012", "18/10/2011", "18/10/2012", "18/11/2011", 
                          "18/11/2012", "18/12/2011", "18/12/2012", "19/01/2011", "19/01/2012", 
                          "19/02/2011", "19/02/2012", "19/03/2011", "19/03/2012", "19/04/2011", 
                          "19/04/2012", "19/05/2011", "19/05/2012", "19/06/2011", "19/06/2012", 
                          "19/07/2011", "19/07/2012", "19/08/2011", "19/08/2012", "19/09/2011", 
                          "19/09/2012", "19/10/2011", "19/10/2012", "19/11/2011", "19/11/2012", 
                          "19/12/2011", "19/12/2012", "20/01/2011", "20/01/2012", "20/02/2011", 
                          "20/02/2012", "20/03/2011", "20/03/2012", "20/04/2011", "20/04/2012", 
                          "20/05/2011", "20/05/2012", "20/06/2011", "20/06/2012", "20/07/2011", 
                          "20/07/2012", "20/08/2011", "20/08/2012", "20/09/2011", "20/09/2012", 
                          "20/10/2011", "20/10/2012", "20/11/2011", "20/11/2012", "20/12/2011", 
                          "20/12/2012", "21/01/2011", "21/01/2012", "21/02/2011", "21/02/2012", 
                          "21/03/2011", "21/03/2012", "21/04/2011", "21/04/2012", "21/05/2011", 
                          "21/05/2012", "21/06/2011", "21/06/2012", "21/07/2011", "21/07/2012", 
                          "21/08/2011", "21/08/2012", "21/09/2011", "21/09/2012", "21/10/2011", 
                          "21/10/2012", "21/11/2011", "21/11/2012", "21/12/2011", "21/12/2012", 
                          "22/01/2011", "22/01/2012", "22/02/2011", "22/02/2012", "22/03/2011", 
                          "22/03/2012", "22/04/2011", "22/04/2012", "22/05/2011", "22/05/2012", 
                          "22/06/2011", "22/06/2012", "22/07/2011", "22/07/2012", "22/08/2011", 
                          "22/08/2012", "22/09/2011", "22/09/2012", "22/10/2011", "22/10/2012", 
                          "22/11/2011", "22/11/2012", "22/12/2011", "22/12/2012", "23/01/2011", 
                          "23/01/2012", "23/02/2011", "23/02/2012", "23/03/2011", "23/03/2012", 
                          "23/04/2011", "23/04/2012", "23/05/2011", "23/05/2012", "23/06/2011", 
                          "23/06/2012", "23/07/2011", "23/07/2012", "23/08/2011", "23/08/2012", 
                          "23/09/2011", "23/09/2012", "23/10/2011", "23/10/2012", "23/11/2011", 
                          "23/11/2012", "23/12/2011", "23/12/2012", "24/01/2011", "24/01/2012", 
                          "24/02/2011", "24/02/2012", "24/03/2011", "24/03/2012", "24/04/2011", 
                          "24/04/2012", "24/05/2011", "24/05/2012", "24/06/2011", "24/06/2012", 
                          "24/07/2011", "24/07/2012", "24/08/2011", "24/08/2012", "24/09/2011", 
                          "24/09/2012", "24/10/2011", "24/10/2012", "24/11/2011", "24/11/2012", 
                          "24/12/2011", "24/12/2012", "25/01/2011", "25/01/2012", "25/02/2011", 
                          "25/02/2012", "25/03/2011", "25/03/2012", "25/04/2011", "25/04/2012", 
                          "25/05/2011", "25/05/2012", "25/06/2011", "25/06/2012", "25/07/2011", 
                          "25/07/2012", "25/08/2011", "25/08/2012", "25/09/2011", "25/09/2012", 
                          "25/10/2011", "25/10/2012", "25/11/2011", "25/11/2012", "25/12/2011", 
                          "25/12/2012", "26/01/2011", "26/01/2012", "26/02/2011", "26/02/2012", 
                          "26/03/2011", "26/03/2012", "26/04/2011", "26/04/2012", "26/05/2011", 
                          "26/05/2012", "26/06/2011", "26/06/2012", "26/07/2011", "26/07/2012", 
                          "26/08/2011", "26/08/2012", "26/09/2011", "26/09/2012", "26/10/2011", 
                          "26/10/2012", "26/11/2011", "26/11/2012", "26/12/2011", "26/12/2012", 
                          "27/01/2011", "27/01/2012", "27/02/2011", "27/02/2012", "27/03/2011", 
                          "27/03/2012", "27/04/2011", "27/04/2012", "27/05/2011", "27/05/2012", 
                          "27/06/2011", "27/06/2012", "27/07/2011", "27/07/2012", "27/08/2011", 
                          "27/08/2012", "27/09/2011", "27/09/2012", "27/10/2011", "27/10/2012", 
                          "27/11/2011", "27/11/2012", "27/12/2011", "27/12/2012", "28/01/2011", 
                          "28/01/2012", "28/02/2011", "28/02/2012", "28/03/2011", "28/03/2012", 
                          "28/04/2011", "28/04/2012", "28/05/2011", "28/05/2012", "28/06/2011", 
                          "28/06/2012", "28/07/2011", "28/07/2012", "28/08/2011", "28/08/2012", 
                          "28/09/2011", "28/09/2012", "28/10/2011", "28/10/2012", "28/11/2011", 
                          "28/11/2012", "28/12/2011", "28/12/2012", "29/01/2011", "29/01/2012", 
                          "29/02/2012", "29/03/2011", "29/03/2012", "29/04/2011", "29/04/2012", 
                          "29/05/2011", "29/05/2012", "29/06/2011", "29/06/2012", "29/07/2011", 
                          "29/07/2012", "29/08/2011", "29/08/2012", "29/09/2011", "29/09/2012", 
                          "29/10/2011", "29/10/2012", "29/11/2011", "29/11/2012", "29/12/2011", 
                          "29/12/2012", "30/01/2011", "30/01/2012", "30/03/2011", "30/03/2012", 
                          "30/04/2011", "30/04/2012", "30/05/2011", "30/05/2012", "30/06/2011", 
                          "30/06/2012", "30/07/2011", "30/07/2012", "30/08/2011", "30/08/2012", 
                          "30/09/2011", "30/09/2012", "30/10/2011", "30/10/2012", "30/11/2011", 
                          "30/11/2012", "30/12/2011", "30/12/2012", "31/01/2011", "31/01/2012", 
                          "31/03/2011", "31/03/2012", "31/05/2011", "31/05/2012", "31/07/2011", 
                          "31/07/2012", "31/08/2011", "31/08/2012", "31/10/2011", "31/10/2012", 
                          "31/12/2011", "31/12/2012"), cnt = c(985L, 2294L, 1360L, 4579L, 
                                                               1851L, 4990L, 2227L, 6041L, 3351L, 5740L, 3974L, 4127L, 5362L, 
                                                               5531L, 4266L, 7580L, 5115L, 6140L, 2429L, 6778L, 4068L, 5986L, 
                                                               3727L, 5191L, 801L, 1951L, 1526L, 3761L, 2134L, 3194L, 2252L, 
                                                               5936L, 4401L, 6169L, 4968L, 8120L, 5119L, 6227L, 4845L, 7261L, 
                                                               4727L, 5810L, 2918L, 4639L, 4186L, 5847L, 3940L, 4649L, 1349L, 
                                                               2236L, 1550L, 4151L, 1685L, 4066L, 3249L, 6772L, 4451L, 6421L, 
                                                               5312L, 7641L, 4649L, 6660L, 3574L, 7175L, 4484L, 6034L, 3570L, 
                                                               7572L, 3974L, 5138L, 3614L, 6234L, 1562L, 2368L, 1708L, 2832L, 
                                                               1944L, 3423L, 3115L, 6436L, 2633L, 6296L, 5342L, 6998L, 6043L, 
                                                               7403L, 4576L, 6824L, 4940L, 6864L, 4456L, 7328L, 4046L, 5107L, 
                                                               3485L, 6606L, 1600L, 3272L, 1005L, 2947L, 2077L, 3333L, 1795L, 
                                                               6457L, 4433L, 6883L, 4906L, 7001L, 4665L, 6241L, 4866L, 5464L, 
                                                               3351L, 7112L, 4826L, 8156L, 3926L, 5259L, 3811L, 5729L, 1606L, 
                                                               4098L, 1623L, 3784L, 605L, 3956L, 2808L, 6460L, 4608L, 6359L, 
                                                               4548L, 7055L, 4629L, 6207L, 4294L, 7013L, 2710L, 6203L, 4765L, 
                                                               7965L, 3649L, 5686L, 2594L, 5375L, 1510L, 4521L, 1712L, 4375L, 
                                                               1872L, 4916L, 3141L, 6857L, 4714L, 6273L, 4833L, 7494L, 4592L, 
                                                               4840L, 3785L, 7273L, 1996L, 7504L, 4985L, 3510L, 4035L, 5035L, 
                                                               705L, 5008L, 959L, 3425L, 1530L, 2802L, 2133L, 5382L, 1471L, 
                                                               5169L, 4333L, 5728L, 4401L, 7736L, 4040L, 4672L, 4326L, 7534L, 
                                                               1842L, 5976L, 5409L, 5478L, 4205L, 5315L, 3322L, 5582L, 822L, 
                                                               2376L, 1605L, 3830L, 1891L, 4569L, 2455L, 5585L, 4362L, 4717L, 
                                                               3915L, 7498L, 5336L, 6569L, 4602L, 7286L, 3544L, 8227L, 5511L, 
                                                               6392L, 4109L, 5992L, 3620L, 3228L, 1321L, 3598L, 1538L, 3831L, 
                                                               4118L, 2895L, 5918L, 4803L, 6572L, 4586L, 6598L, 4881L, 6290L, 
                                                               4780L, 5786L, 5345L, 7525L, 5117L, 7691L, 2933L, 6536L, 3190L, 
                                                               5170L, 1263L, 2177L, 1746L, 2169L, 1977L, 4911L, 3348L, 4862L, 
                                                               4182L, 7030L, 4966L, 6664L, 4086L, 7264L, 4792L, 6299L, 5046L, 
                                                               7767L, 4563L, 7570L, 3368L, 6852L, 2743L, 5501L, 1162L, 4097L, 
                                                               1472L, 1529L, 2132L, 5298L, 2034L, 5409L, 4864L, 7429L, 4460L, 
                                                               4972L, 4258L, 7446L, 4905L, 6544L, 4713L, 7870L, 2416L, 7282L, 
                                                               4067L, 6269L, 3310L, 5319L, 1406L, 3214L, 1589L, 3422L, 2417L, 
                                                               5847L, 2162L, 6398L, 4105L, 6118L, 5020L, 7421L, 4342L, 7499L, 
                                                               4150L, 6883L, 4763L, 7804L, 2913L, 7109L, 3717L, 4094L, 3523L, 
                                                               5532L, 1421L, 2493L, 1913L, 3922L, 2046L, 6312L, 3267L, 7460L, 
                                                               3409L, 2843L, 4891L, 7363L, 5084L, 6969L, 3820L, 6784L, 4785L, 
                                                               8009L, 3644L, 6639L, 4486L, 5495L, 3740L, 5611L, 1248L, 2311L, 
                                                               1815L, 4169L, 2056L, 6192L, 3126L, 7132L, 4553L, 5115L, 5180L, 
                                                               7665L, 5538L, 6031L, 4338L, 7347L, 3659L, 8714L, 5217L, 5875L, 
                                                               4195L, 5445L, 3709L, 5047L, 1204L, 2298L, 2115L, 3005L, 2192L, 
                                                               4378L, 795L, 6370L, 3958L, 7424L, 3767L, 7702L, 5923L, 6830L, 
                                                               4725L, 7605L, 4760L, 7333L, 5041L, 7534L, 1817L, 5698L, 3577L, 
                                                               3786L, 1000L, 2935L, 2475L, 4154L, 2744L, 7836L, 3744L, 6691L, 
                                                               4123L, 7384L, 4844L, 6978L, 5302L, 6786L, 4694L, 7148L, 4511L, 
                                                               6869L, 4570L, 7461L, 3053L, 5629L, 2739L, 4585L, 683L, 3376L, 
                                                               2927L, 4318L, 3239L, 5892L, 3429L, 4367L, 3855L, 7639L, 5119L, 
                                                               5099L, 4458L, 5713L, 3805L, 7865L, 4274L, 4073L, 4748L, 7509L, 
                                                               3392L, 4669L, 2431L, 5557L, 1650L, 3292L, 1635L, 2689L, 3117L, 
                                                               6153L, 3204L, 6565L, 4575L, 8294L, 4744L, 6825L, 4541L, 6591L, 
                                                               4153L, 4549L, 4539L, 7591L, 2424L, 5424L, 3663L, 5499L, 3403L, 
                                                               5267L, 1927L, 3163L, 1812L, 3129L, 2471L, 6093L, 3944L, 7290L, 
                                                               4917L, 7129L, 4010L, 6211L, 4332L, 5870L, 5191L, 6530L, 3641L, 
                                                               7720L, 4195L, 8090L, 3520L, 5634L, 3750L, 4128L, 1543L, 1301L, 
                                                               1107L, 3777L, 2077L, 6230L, 4189L, 6624L, 5805L, 4359L, 4835L, 
                                                               5905L, 3784L, 4459L, 3873L, 7006L, 4352L, 8167L, 4304L, 6824L, 
                                                               2765L, 5146L, 2660L, 3623L, 981L, 1977L, 1450L, 4773L, 2703L, 
                                                               6871L, 1683L, 1027L, 4660L, 6073L, 4507L, 5823L, 3387L, 7410L, 
                                                               4758L, 7375L, 4795L, 8395L, 4308L, 7058L, 1607L, 2425L, 3068L, 
                                                               1749L, 986L, 2432L, 1917L, 5062L, 2121L, 8362L, 4036L, 3214L, 
                                                               4274L, 5260L, 4790L, 7458L, 3285L, 6966L, 5895L, 7765L, 2395L, 
                                                               7907L, 4381L, 7466L, 2566L, 3910L, 2209L, 1787L, 1416L, 4339L, 
                                                               1807L, 3487L, 1865L, 3372L, 4191L, 5633L, 4492L, 6770L, 4991L, 
                                                               6891L, 3606L, 7592L, 5130L, 7582L, 5423L, 7436L, 4187L, 7693L, 
                                                               1495L, 2277L, 1011L, 920L, 1985L, 4270L, 1461L, 2732L, 2210L, 
                                                               4996L, 4073L, 6196L, 4978L, 6734L, 5202L, 6779L, 3840L, 8173L, 
                                                               3542L, 6053L, 5010L, 7538L, 4687L, 7359L, 2792L, 2424L, 754L, 
                                                               1013L, 506L, 4075L, 1969L, 3389L, 2496L, 5558L, 4400L, 5026L, 
                                                               4677L, 6536L, 5305L, 7442L, 4590L, 6861L, 4661L, 5255L, 4630L, 
                                                               7733L, 3894L, 7444L, 3068L, 5087L, 1317L, 441L, 431L, 3456L, 
                                                               2402L, 4322L, 1693L, 5102L, 3872L, 6233L, 4679L, 6591L, 4708L, 
                                                               7335L, 4656L, 6904L, 1115L, 6917L, 4120L, 7393L, 2659L, 7852L, 
                                                               3071L, 3959L, 1162L, 2114L, 1167L, 4023L, 1446L, 4363L, 2028L, 
                                                               5698L, 4058L, 4220L, 4758L, 6043L, 4648L, 6879L, 4390L, 6685L, 
                                                               4334L, 7040L, 3907L, 7415L, 3747L, 4459L, 3867L, 5260L, 2302L, 
                                                               3095L, 1098L, 3243L, 1834L, 2425L, 6133L, 4595L, 6304L, 4788L, 
                                                               5743L, 5225L, 5463L, 3846L, 6597L, 4634L, 7697L, 4839L, 8555L, 
                                                               627L, 22L, 2914L, 5323L, 2423L, 1341L, 1096L, 3624L, 1536L, 5459L, 
                                                               5312L, 5572L, 4098L, 6855L, 5515L, 5687L, 4475L, 7105L, 5204L, 
                                                               7713L, 5202L, 6889L, 3331L, 1096L, 3613L, 5668L, 2999L, 1796L, 
                                                               1501L, 4509L, 1685L, 6235L, 3982L, 7338L, 4302L, 7216L, 5058L, 
                                                               7350L, 3669L, 5566L, 2485L, 2729L)), row.names = c(NA, -730L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make this line chart show mmyyyy as the x axis, cnt as the y axis and add colors to this line chart.

This is the current line that I have but it is not what I wanted.
Even though I have already stated the x axis, y axis and the color, it still does not show up on the plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=dteday, y=cnt, group = 1))+
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title = "Bike Rentals According to Month",
  x = "Month/Year",
  y = "Count",
  color = "lightblue") + 
  theme_fivethirtyeight()
```

[image]

The desired outcome will be to have 24 points on the graph (12 months from 2011 and 2012) and to have a seamless line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently do not realize that your "dates" are actually character values and have the 2011 and 2012 values mixed together because character values are sorted on the basis of the leading characters which in your case are the days of the month. It completely confuses any proper estimation of seasonal trends, so the first thing to do is fix that by constructing a "true" R Date value, and then use `geom_smooth` to create a sensible trend line:

```
df$dt <- as.Date(df$dteday, format="%d/%m/%Y")
 ggplot(df, aes(x=dt, y=cnt, group = 1))+
     geom_line() + 
     labs(title = "Bike Rentals According to Month",
          x = "Month/Year",
          y = "Count",
          color = "lightblue") + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

As can be seen in the `?geom_smooth` page, the smoother used for series with fewer than a 1000 points is `loess`, so you can see the parameters that might be available to tweak this polynomial approximation at the `?loess` page. I tried to increase the degree of the polynomial fit by adding `degree=3` to the geom_smooth parameters, and got an error. So perhaps you would be more satisfied by adding `method="gam"`. (I was.)

Obviously that means you now need to do a bit of further work at getting the tick marks and labels fixed up to use "true" R Date values. I'm pretty sure that information is available on SO.  In the future you should also include `library` calls to load fancy themes that are not in ggplot.

Comment: ahh thats why my date values were jumbled up. Thanks!